# XML mapping xtr no muestra datos

Tags: xml

tengo el siguiente problema usé la herramienta XML mapping para hacerl el mapeo de un XML (http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/Pagos/Pagos10.xsd).

Creo el *.xtr, el problema que cuando intento abrir el ClientDataSet, este muestra un renglon, pero vacío en blanco.

No sé si me expliqué bien.

En otras palabras quiero abrir el contenido de un complemento de pago del sat(xml), para esto uso XMLTransformProvider un TransformationFile (el .xtr que generé con el XML mapping) y conecto un ClientDataSet, pero cuando abro me muestra el renglón vacío.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta a mi pregunta resultó ser muy simple. Únicamente que el nombre de los campos en *.xtr son casesensitive. Es decir debe ser tal cual como está el nombre en el XML. Mi error era que leía un campo "Version" y en el *.xtr decía "version".

Gracias de cualquier manera.